# Canvas Position (x,y)

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have an ItemsControl that has a collection source, the items appear in canvas and I can move them with mouse events, How I can save position of an Item (x,y)?

This is my code :

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="icTables" Padding="0,30,0,0" Margin="249,88,0,115" Width="737" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="#FF6C6C6C" BorderThickness="1">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <jas:DragCanvas x:Name="drCanvas"></jas:DragCanvas>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="btnTable" Foreground="#ff252526" Width="75" Height="75">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TableNo}" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFECECEC"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ToggleButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `Canvas.GetLeft` and `Canvas.GetTop` methods?

Comment: How is the DragCanvas moved? Is it by a rendertransform (translation) or by setting the Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left ?

Comment: Canvas here is itmepanel, I can't use drCanvas.GetLeft in code behined

Comment: by setting the Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left

Comment: Have you tried binding the "Canvas.Top" and "Canvas.Left" to properties of the items in the items control. That way you would only have to query the properties on the items.

Comment: Erno de Weerd, Can you explain that with code please?

Answer (score 0):

You can either foreach all items inside your Canvas, retrieve their Left and Top values and store them or you can do a TwoWay data binding between the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties and 2 matching properties in your Item ViewModels and store the values there.

Answer (score 0):

probably you should extend DragCanvas, when drag done event raised, you should save the position info to item(via attached dependency property).

```
drCanvas.DragCompleted +=(s,e)=>
{
   var pos = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
   ToggleButton.SetValue(PositionAttachedDependencyProperty,pos);
};
```